# Connection timmed out when accessing Tomcat web manager

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ubuntu-server

I installed tomcat8 on a amazon ubuntu server from a windows computer using an online tutorial as a guide.

It started from command line, a message stated it was really running, but when I try to access the webapp, I get connection timmed out.

I went through a lot of possible online solutions, so I edited my tomcat-users.xml, my server.xml, but I dont get to load the app when I enter http://server_ip:8080

When I try localhost:8080 I get access denied.

How can I verify what is wrong, please?

Oh, I also added tomcat user, group and exported catalina path.

I'm really new to ubuntu, could you guys help me? Obrigada

this is what i get from catalina.out

```
        17-Oct-2016 14:41:36.789 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:228)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:866)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:213)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:575)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:944)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:873)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)

17-Oct-2016 14:41:36.791 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:873)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)



17-Oct-2016 05:04:02.282 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]:
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
```

The thing is, Im not using these ports anymore, I changed them in server.xml file to port 80.

Comment: Have you checked the Tomcat's log files (`catalina.out` file, usually in `$TOMCAT_HOME/logs` folder)? Are there any errors? Because the console message after executing `startup.sh` just says the startup process has been fired, but nothing about its result.

Comment: Yes I have.
I'll update the question, thanks so much

Comment: @JozefChocholacek done. but the thing is, Im not using those ports listed. I actually was first using 8080 but then it appeared to be already in use that not tomcat, and since I was not being able to connect, I though I had to change port number

Answer (score 0):

What actually worked for me was opening 8080 port on aws. As simple as that haha :)